# Printing iframe gives error

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am loading a html page with iframe on my current document iframe. The code for the current document is

```
<iframe id="pdfFrame" name="pdf1" onload="LoadPrint();" 
style="height:1000px;width:1000px;"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">

function LoadPDF(filename)
{
    var loc = "pdf-loader.html?pdfframe="+filename;
    document.getElementById("pdf").setAttribute("src", loc);
}

function LoadPrint() {
    alert('fired!');
    if (document.getElementById("pdf").src !== "") {
        var frm = document.getElementById("pdf");
    frm.contentDocument.getElementById("pdfframe").contentWindow.print();
    }
}

</script>
```

LoadPDF is called from code behind. This loads a pdf file in another page. After which I copy the contents into current document's iframe.
As soon as my current document is loaded 'fired'/ LoadPrint() is triggered. I then try and print the iframe contents but I get an error  'Invalid calling object'. Please help

The second html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>PDF Loader</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}

#pdf {
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="pdfframe"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">

function getParameterByName(name) {
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

var pdf = getParameterByName('pdf');
document.getElementById('pdfframe').setAttribute('src', pdf);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is element having `id` of `"pdf"` at `html`?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: There still does not appear to be an element having `id` set to `"pdf"` at `html` at Question?

Comment: pdf is in the main document